# Excel VBA MySQL "SELECT * FROM table" not full informaton

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, excel

I have a really weird issue with my Excel VBA code selecting values from a MySQL database. I structured a simple database with following columns:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Surname
4. City

And lets assume having following entrys:

01; Pan; Peter; NYC
02; P; Peter; NYC

But now the issue, if I select * from my table it shows me only following output:

01; P; Pan; NYC
02; P; Pan; NYC

That means the I only see the minimal lenght of an entry .... what is going on there? I have really casual VBA code in different modules for that task:

**Public variables:**

```
Public cn As ADODB.Connection
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset
Public strSql As String
```

**Connection module:**

```
Public Function connectDB()
Dim strServer_Name As String
Dim strDB_Name As String
Dim strUser_ID As String
Dim strPassword As String

With Sheet2
    strServer_Name = .Range("B2").Value
    strDB_Name = .Range("B3").Value
    strUser_ID = .Range("B4").Value
    strPassword = .Range("B5").Value
End With

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver}" & _
";SERVER=" & strServer_Name & _
";DATABASE=" & strDB_Name & _
";UID=" & strUser_ID & _
";PWD=" & strPassword & ""
End Function
```

**Sub module:**

```
Sub request()
strSql = "SELECT * FROM test"

Call connectDB
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strSql, cn, adOpenDynamic

With Sheet1.Range("A1")
    .ClearContents
    .CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

Call disconnectDB
End Sub
```

Is this a VBA issue or are there any bugs in my MySQL?

Comment: Are you able to query the database directly via command line or phpmyadmin? If so, do you get the same results? Are you able to verify that they char() or varchar() length of the fields appropriate for the data you are inserting?

Comment: There's nothing in your code which accounts for what you're seeing in the output.

Comment: Are you sure the columns are wide enough and that you just can't see all that data that's there? Also, replace the CopyFromRecordset to see if that's the problem. `Do:Debug.Print rs.Fields(2).Value: rs.MoveNext: Loop Until rs.EOF` Do you get unexpected results?

Comment: it shouldn't make any difference but try replacing the sql string with this "select ID, Name, Surname, City from test"

Comment: @JNevill: I am able to query directly in phpmyadmin and get the correct results. The data types of the fields are int(11) for ID and TEXT for all other fields. I will add the screenshot of the phpmyadmin query to the question.

But I recocnized something really weird again. The bug only occures if the LAST entry of the table has a lower lenght then the other entrys. So if the last entry has the same length as the max. lenght of all other entrys it showhs everything. Individual for each column. I also will add Screenshots to the question.

Comment: I couldn't attach picutres to my question so i try to show it to you here. 

mysql:
1; Pan; Peter; NYC
1; P; Peter; NYC

result: 
1; P; Peter; NYC
1; P; Peter; NYC

BUT if the last entry has again the correct lenght it shows everything. 

mysql:
1; Pan; Peter; NYC
1; P; Peter; NYC
1; Pan; Peter; NYC

result:
1; Pan; Peter; NYC
1; P; Peter; NYC
1; Pan; Peter; NYC

So is this a mysql configuration issue? I am totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys I've found a solution in this post: [sql-query-doesnt-return-full-results-for-only-one-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228328/sql-query-doesnt-return-full-results-for-only-one-field)

Solved it the same way the other guy did. In my code it looks like this:

```
Sub request()
Dim iCols As Integer
Dim iRows As Integer

strSql = "SELECT * FROM test"

Call connectDB
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strSql, cn, adOpenDynamic

iRows = 10

While Not rs.EOF
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Tabelle1.Cells(iRows, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Value
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
    iRows = iRows + 1
Wend

Call disconnectDB
End Sub
```

But thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Comment: So the solution is to go cell by cell and retrieve the data? There must be some funky sauce in the mysql odbc adapter.

Comment: it seems so but yes thats the solution

Comment: I wonder. The one guy seemed to fix it by explicitly casting (but his answer wasn't the accepted one) which would indicate that the MySQL driver has a bug (presumably he still used CopyFromRecordset). But the OP here isn't CASTing anything, rather he's avoiding the CopyFromRecordset method, which would indicate that the Excel Object Model has a bug. Although I've used CopyFromRecordset many times (not with MySQL) and never seen the problem. So maybe the bug lies with communication between CopyFromRecordset and the MySQL driver.