# Run-time error 'I004': Application defined or Object Defined Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting this error. All My data is In targetArray, which has about 152 lines. But it paste only 81 lines and I get this error.

I gett he error when it tries to run the following line in the code :

```
WBook.Worksheets(strWorksheet).Range(strAddress).Value = TargetArray
Set WBook = Nothing
```

My Main code is

```
Sub GetData(Optional OnOpen As Boolean = False)

Dim vrntQryList() As Variant
Dim vrntQryData() As Variant
Dim vrntRptGrp() As Variant
Dim intQryListCol As Integer
Dim strQry As String
Dim strRptGrp As String

'This subroutine imports new data. The OnOpen indicator modifies where the data is put after it runs

On Error GoTo GameOver

'choose which column to look for the range name based on whether or not this is run on open or not
If OnOpen Then
    intQryListCol = 3
Else
    intQryListCol = 2
End If

'Get the list of queries
vrntQryList = AF_RngToArray("DT_QryList")
vrntRptGrp = AF_RngToArray("DT_RptGrp")

'Make the report groups a list
strRptGrp = VF_ArrayToList(vrntRptGrp, 1)

'Loop through the query list
For i = 1 To UBound(vrntQryList)

    If vrntQryList(i, intQryListCol) <> "" Then

        'Set the query to this variable so we can run the replace function to get placeholders
        strQry = vrntQryList(i, 1)
        strQry = Replace(strQry, "|USERID|", Environ("Username"))
        strQry = Replace(strQry, "|RPTGRP|", strRptGrp)

        'Get the new data from the database
        vrntQryData = AF_QryToArray_AXS(ThisWorkbook.Names("DT_DBPath").RefersToRange.Value, strQry)

        'Only continue and clear out the ranges if we know that we returned new data
        If SafeUbound(vrntQryData) <> 0 Then

            ThisWorkbook.Names(vrntQryList(i, intQryListCol)).RefersToRange.ClearContents

            Call PasteArray(vrntQryData, CStr(vrntQryList(i, intQryListCol)))
        Else
            GoTo GameOver
        End If

    End If

Next i

Exit Sub

'If there's an error just back out and let the user know
GameOver:

'If we make it down here and we are not running with the OnOpen indicator set to TRUE then let the user know we don't have new data for them
If Not OnOpen Then
    MsgBox "Error importing new data. Most likely you don't have access to the required LAN drive.", , "ERROR IN DATA IMPORT"
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub PasteArray(TargetArray() As Variant, RangeName As String, Optional blNotThisWorkbook As Boolean = False)

'The purpose of this function is to be able to transfer data from an array in VBA back into a
'named range in excel

Dim strWorksheet As String
Dim strAddress As String
Dim cntRows As Long
Dim cntCols As Long
Dim WBook As Workbook
Dim rngCols As Long
Dim rngRows As Long

'Check if the array is empty, if it is then exit the sub
If SafeUbound(TargetArray) = 0 Then Exit Sub

If blNotThisWorkbook Then
    Set WBook = ActiveWorkbook
Else
    Set WBook = ThisWorkbook
End If

'Clear out the paste range to start
WBook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.ClearContents

'Find the name of the target worksheet
strWorksheet = WBook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name

'Find the size of the range we are pasting to
rngCols = WBook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.Columns.Count
rngRows = WBook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.Rows.Count

'Find the number of rows and columns
cntRows = UBound(TargetArray)
cntCols = UBound(TargetArray, 2)

'Check to make sure the array will fit in the range we are pasting to.
'trip an error here if desired
If cntRows > rngRows Or cntCols > rngCols Then
    Set WBook = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

'Get the exact size of the range, based on the amount of data in it
SplitAd = Split(WBook.Names(RangeName).RefersToRange.Address, ":")
strAddress = SplitAd(0) & ":" & Range(SplitAd(0)).Offset(cntRows - 1, cntCols - 1).Address

'Drop down the array into the range
WBook.Worksheets(strWorksheet).Range(strAddress).Value = TargetArray
Set WBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `WBook.Worksheets(strWorksheet).Range(strAddress).Value` assignment instruction, inspect the value of `strAddress`. Ctrl+G and type `?strAddress` - what does it say? Looks like a legit address?

Comment: StrWorksheet has value "Raw Data" and StrAddress  has value "$C$13:$AZ$164"    data starts pasting from line 13 , and total lines are 153, so that is why it goes up to AZ $164

Comment: This code used to work ok, something in data is throwing it off, it paste up to line 81

Comment: Have you tried assigning a single cell's value to `TargetArray`? e.g. `$C$13` instead? Otherwise it could be an off-by-one error in your sizing, i.e. the data you're dumping is larger than the range you're dumping it in - I'm pretty sure dumping to the top-left cell of the target range should work.

Comment: As far as I know my range is ='Raw Data'!$C$13:$AZ$5248     Would you give me more  SIMPLE steps I can follow? , I am not too familiar with VBA

Comment: `WBook.Worksheets(strWorksheet).Range("C13").Value = TargetArray`

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks for trying Matt, I get the same error

Comment: What is `LBound(TargetArray, 1)` and `LBound(TargetArray, 2)`?

Comment: @YowE3K fine ;-) I assume `TargetArray` was assigned directly from a `Range` though

Comment: @Mat'sMug - I spoke too soon - if it was zero-based your code would have worked.

Comment: FWIW - the original code works for me, using a simplistic scenario.  What is the value of `strWorksheet` and `strAddress` when it crashes?  And what are the LBounds and UBounds of `TargetArray`?

Comment: StrWorksheet has value "Raw Data" and StrAddress has value "$C$13:$AZ$164"

Comment: Function SafeUbound(TargetArray() As Variant, Optional dimension As Integer = 1)

On Error GoTo GameOver

'Return the normal ubound and exit the function
SafeUbound = UBound(TargetArray, dimension)

Exit Function

GameOver:

'If the normal ubound errors, we know that this is an empty array
SafeUbound = 0

End Function

Comment: I wasn't particularly concerned about that function, but can you just type `?LBound(TargetArray, 1) & "|" & UBound(TargetArray, 1) & "|" & LBound(TargetArray, 2) & "|" & UBound(TargetArray, 2)` into the Immediate window please - that will then tell us how big the array is that you are trying to copy.

Comment: LBound(TargetArray, 1)  =   1        UBound(TargetArray, 1) = 152   LBound(TargetArray, 2)  = 1     UBound(TargetArray, 2) = 50

Comment: I'm stumped - if `TargetArray` is a `Variant` array dimensioned `(1 To 152, 1 To 50)` (as evidenced by the LBounds/UBounds) and `strWorksheet` is `"Raw Data"` and `strAddress` is `"$C$13:$AZ$164"`, then I can't see any reason why `WBook.Worksheets(strWorksheet).Range(strAddress).Value = TargetArray` should fail with an "Application defined or Object Defined" error.

Comment: another weird thing is ,It does Paste Data but only partial data, only up to 81 records, nothing after that

Comment: Do you have something weird in row 82 of `TargetArray`?  Error values? (I tested that, and that didn't crash for me, but maybe I didn't test properly?)  Something else that isn't valid as a `Value`?  How was `TargetArray` created?  Just read from some other range in Excel?  Is there something weird about the place you would be putting row 82 in the destination?  Merged cells?  (Hmm - I didn't test that one!)

Comment: row 85 , column 5 is " "    , it is blank in the database  ( usual value is Last name, First name),, other than that rest of the line looks normal to me. I run the qry in access database,and pull the data

Comment: I vaguely remember there being a problem with `NULL` from SQL queries.  I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10228328/6535336) which might help.  If I find anything else I'll provide more links.

Comment: I can't find anything definitive, but everything I did find seems to suggest modifying your query to change any Nulls to be valid data (e.g. use `IIF([First Name] Is Null, "", [First Name])` instead of `[First Name]` in your query).

Comment: Thanks ,I added the main code to see, if that helps us in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TargetArray is a 1-based 2-D array:

```
WBook.Worksheets(strWorksheet).Range(strAddress).Cells(1).Resize( _
    UBound(TargetArray, 1), UBound(TargetArray, 2)).Value = TargetArray
```

Comment: Tim, i am getting the same error. Thanks for your time